# Pandas Filtering Data Based on what appears at the start

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Q':['chair', 'desk', '-----monitor', 'chair'], 'R':['red', '-- use blue  or dark blue', 'yellow', 'purple'], 'S': ['-- is english spoken?', 'german', 'spanish', 'english']})


              Q                       R                                S
0         chair                     Red            -- is english spoken?
1          desk    -- blue or dark blue                           german
2  -----monitor                  yellow                          spanish
3         chair                  purple                          english
```

what I want to be returned:

```
              Q                       R                                S
3         chair                  purple                          english
```

I want to filter out the entire row if any column has a "-" value that appears 2 or more times at the beginning.

I found a thread for filtering numerical values, but is there any way to filter out special characters? Particularly with regex?

**Edit #1:**

I am only looking to remove rows if "-" appears 2 or more times at the very beginning. If that value appears in the middle of some text, that's fine.

Let's say my dataframe looks like this:

```
              Q                       R                                S
0         chair                     Red            -- is english spoken?
1          desk       blue or dark blue                           ger--man
2  -----monitor                  yellow                          spanish
3         chair                  purple                          english
```

I would have this returned:

```
              Q                       R                                S
1          desk       blue or dark blue                           ger--man
3         chair                  purple                          english
```

**Edit #2:**

I have tried this:

```
df4[~df4.Q.str.startswith(('--'))]
```

But this only works on 1 column, not all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `applymap` with `in` and `any`

```
df4[~df4.applymap(lambda x : '--' in x).any(1)]
Out[287]: 
       Q       R        S
3  chair  purple  english
```

Update only exclude the certain at the beginning.

```
df4[~df4.applymap(lambda x : str.startswith(x,'--')).any(1)]
```

Comment: Maybe more complicated  OP need `I want to filter out the entire row if any column has a "-" value that appears 2 or more times at the beginning.`

Comment: I am currently testing Wen's solution. This may be a topic for another thread, but I don't entirely understand this part: "lambda x: - in x" none of my columns are named x?

Comment: This filters out if there is at least 1, but I need two or more. I am playing around with what you gave me though

Comment: couldn't you change the above code to:
`df4[~df4.applymap(lambda x : '--' in x).any(1)]`

Comment: Actually, that's a great idea

Comment: That works. I am going to mark Wen's answer as the solution though because he already has it posted and your answer is just a small variation of that.

Comment: That removes the row if 2 or more dashes appear anywhere. I only want the beginning. I modified my original question if that helps.

Comment: @LunchBox change to `df4.applymap(lambda x : str.startswith(x,'--'))
`

Comment: Actually, quick question Wen, when I run this, it returns all rows as either true or false. Is there anyway I can prevent that?

Comment: @LunchBox did you add any ? `ddf4[~df4.applymap(lambda x : str.startswith(x,'--')).any(1)]`

Comment: Tried it with and without

Comment: @LunchBox base on your example,  on my side it return 0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False

Comment: Correct, I wanted to return the rows with the actual values still in them after filtering.

Comment: @LunchBox then `df4[~df4.applymap(lambda x : str.startswith(x,'--')).any(1)]`

Comment: ah, I didn't notice you posted another version of this. I was trying df4.applymap(lambda x : str.startswith(x,'--')). When I use your new version, all is well.

Comment: It's stripping off the values though, I'm going to edit my post in 1 minute

Comment: Actually, it wasn't stripping off the values, I was looking at the row index values.

I am good now, my problem is solved. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Wen: What dictates whether or not you get "true / false" returned or the actual record value? I have another situation where this is happening and I am curious.

Comment: If I do a filter, I can get 1 of 2 results. I can get true/false values or I can get the actual value back.

The solution you gave me earlier, gave me exactly what I needed, but what dictates whether I get true/false back or the actual value back on true records returned?

does that make sense?

Comment: I think it might be better if I post a separate question for this one. Will do in just a sec